# IBM Watson Text to Speech service the return wav seem to not include all the text

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I'm testing IBM watson's text-to-speech service, and I'm using the curl method, I finally got the command to work.

When I submit text(less than 5kb) I get a wav file that doesn't contains all the text. It's cut off at around 3 min into it.

Comment: the curl command seem to stop at 30 sec, but i set the --max-time 900. is there anything else? or is there some limit on IBM's side?

Comment: can you post the curl command you're using? (without the credentials of course)

Comment: Can you check if you are exceeding the payload limits for the Watson TTS service? They are in described in the documentation

Comment: My .wav file is unreadable, can you help?